# Как передать разные данные в функцию Python, запущенную в многопоточном режиме

Tags: python, многопоточность

Хочу узнать, можно ли как-то запустить Python функцию в многопотоке, при этом передав разные параметры для каждого потока. То есть, к примеру, запустить функцию парсинга в 4 потока и каждому потоку передать свою таблицу в базе данных?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Достаточно импортировать библиотеку `threading` создать поток и передать туда функцию

```
import threading
import time

def thread_function(name):
    print("Thread %s: starting", name)
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Thread %s: finishing", name)

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    threads = []
    for i in range(6):
        t = threading.Thread(target=thread_function, args=(i,))
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)
    print("Main    : wait for the thread to finish")
    for t in threads:
        t.join()
    print("Main    : all done")
```

Comment: то есть, если мне нужно 6 потоков, я сделаю 6 перемененных, по типу t1, t2, t3... и буду передавать в них разные аргументы?

Comment: можно в цикле в массив создавать

Comment: а можете приложить код как это сделать? Я просто никогда не работал с многопоточностью, сейчас стараюсь разбираться. Спасибо

Comment: @IIIyTH1K добавил